# Get Customer Data from Sheet where Data in one sheet equals data in another sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

This is my first post/question - I have 2 Sheets, one sheet Called Fund Data, the other called Billable Transactions. on Billable transactions I have ID Data in Column A & Customer Data in column D. In Fund Data, I have ID data in Column R. In a separate sheet, I am trying to bring in Customer Data whose ID (on the Billable Transaction sheet) equals the ID in Fund Data sheet in the Column R. Let me know if any further clarification is needed & thanks so much in advance!

I tried using a VLOOKUP but I can't figure out using a VLOOKUP while matching IDs between 2 separate sheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fund data sheet use `XLOOKUP()` function. Try-

```
=XLOOKUP(R2,'Billable Transactions'!A:A,'Billable Transactions'!D:D)
```